# Array of Hashes to CSV with Ruby

Tags: ruby, arrays, csv, hash

I'm working on creating a CSV file of orders from an array of hashes. The name and id in the CSV output need to be the same on each line, but the amount of lines for each order depends on the amount of skus that are in the order.

Is there a simple way to output this orders array?

```
orders = []
orders << { name:"bob", id:123, sku:[ "123a", "456b", "xyz1" ], qty:[ 2, 4, 1 ] }
orders << { name:"kat", id:987, sku:[ "456b", "aaa0", "xyz1" ], qty:[ 8, 9, 5 ] }
orders << { name:"kat", id:222, sku:[ "123a" ], qty:[ 4 ] }
```

To a CSV file like this:

```
name,id,sku,qty
bob,123,123a,2
bob,123,456b,4
bob,123,xyz1,1
kat,987,456b,8
kat,987,aaa0,9
kat,987,xyz1,5
kat,222,123a,4
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. When asking a question like this, it behoves you to supply a sample of the code you've written to solve the problem. Failing to do that makes it look like you want someone else to write it for you, which isn't good.

Comment: This about the task of reworking code that someone else writes and is totally unrelated to what you'd written. That's a potential bug right there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, let’s prepare the array to dump to CSV:

```
asarray = orders.map { |e| 
  [e[:name], e[:id], e[:sku].zip(e[:qty])] 
}.map { |e| 
  e.last.map { |sq| [*e[0..1], *sq] } 
}
```

Now we have raw array ready to be serialized to CSV:

```
require 'csv'
CSV.open("path/to/file.csv", "wb") do |csv|
  csv << ["name", "id", "sku", "qty"]
  asarray.each { |order|
    order.each { |row|
      csv << row
    }
  }
end
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
module SKUSeparator
  def map_by_skus
    inject([]) do |csv, order|
      order[:sku].each_with_index do |sku, index|
        csv << [order[:name], order[:id], order[:sku][index], order[:qty][index]]
      end
      csv
    end
  end

  def to_csv
    map_by_skus.map { |line| line.join(",") }.join("\n")
  end
end

ORDERS = [
  {:name=>"bob", :id=>123, :sku=>["123a", "456b", "xyz1"], :qty=>[2, 4, 1]},
  {:name=>"kat", :id=>987, :sku=>["456b", "aaa0", "xyz1"], :qty=>[8, 9, 5]},
  {:name=>"kat", :id=>222, :sku=>["123a"], :qty=>[4]}
]

ORDERS.extend(SKUSeparator).map_by_skus # =>

# [
#   ["bob", 123, "123a", 2],
#   ["bob", 123, "456b", 4],
#   ["bob", 123, "xyz1", 1],
#   ["kat", 987, "456b", 8],
#   ["kat", 987, "aaa0", 9],
#   ["kat", 987, "xyz1", 5],
#   ["kat", 222, "123a", 4]
# ]

ORDERS.extend(SKUSeparator).to_csv # =>

# bob,123,123a,2
# bob,123,456b,4
# bob,123,xyz1,1
# kat,987,456b,8
# kat,987,aaa0,9
# kat,987,xyz1,5
# kat,222,123a,4
```

Answer (score 1):

As a variant:

```
orders = []
orders << { name:"bob", id:123, sku:[ "123a", "456b", "xyz1" ], qty:[ 2, 4, 1 ] }
orders << { name:"kat", id:987, sku:[ "456b", "aaa0", "xyz1" ], qty:[ 8, 9, 5 ] }
orders << { name:"kat", id:222, sku:[ "123a" ], qty:[ 4 ] }

csv = ''
orders.each do |el|
  el[:qty].length.times do |idx|
    csv += "#{el[:name]},#{el[:id]},#{el[:sku][idx]},#{el[:qty][idx]}\n"
  end
end
puts csv
```

Result:

```
#> bob,123,123a,2
#> bob,123,456b,4
#> bob,123,xyz1,1
#> kat,987,456b,8
#> kat,987,aaa0,9
#> kat,987,xyz1,5
#> kat,222,123a,4
```